# Ensuring files on the fly are not compressed to zero byte

Tags: .htaccess

Gzip is enabled, i requested for site whose size is 2.7kb. Unfortunately the site was compressed to zero byte. How do you state code in htaccess to ensure files should not be compressed to zero byte on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

No file, when compressed, is ZERO bytes. It's more likely that your transfer failed. Here's an example, using the smallest file I can create (zero bytes):

```
$ touch zerobytes.demonstration
$ ls -l zerobytes.demonstration
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt 0 Oct 21 11:26 zerobytes.demonstration
$ gzip -9 --verbose zerobytes.demonstration
zerobytes.demonstration:      0.0% -- replaced with zerobytes.demonstration.gz
$ ls -l zerobytes.demonstration.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt 44 Oct 21 11:26 zerobytes.demonstration.gz
$ od -bc zerobytes.demonstration.gz
0000000 037 213 010 010 272 256 047 126 002 003 172 145 162 157 142 171
        037 213  \b  \b 272 256   '   V 002 003   z   e   r   o   b   y
0000020 164 145 163 056 144 145 155 157 156 163 164 162 141 164 151 157
          t   e   s   .   d   e   m   o   n   s   t   r   a   t   i   o
0000040 156 000 003 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
          n  \0 003  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000054
$
```